# concatenate url query to sync pagination and search

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, history

I'm developing SPA, and I have advance search and pagination. Damn it's harder than I think to keep both in sync. Previously I've done both feature but realized they are not in sync. For example you searched something, says I got 30 results, I have 10 limit per page, you click on the second page, suppose I also have to pass back your search queries, and vice versa, like you navigate to the second page, you search something, I have to pass back my current page number which is 2.

I found a way to do it, but stuck and doing a lot of manual and parsing with query string. Any package can make my life easier? Tried querystring and history, both is not great.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React Router, using the route you can specify the parameters in the path i.e.

```
<Route path="/view/:search/:page" component={Search} />
```

Then in your component you can access the search and page using:

```
this.props.params.page
```

and

```
this.props.params.search
```